# excel active x control button is not working suddenly

Tags: excel, activex, excel-2013

I'm working with excel macro-enabled files,

Today I just found out the button i made was not working-cannot be click- which was working yesterday.
And digging up the matter,
I found out that other Activce X controls is not working also, and I cannot event insert Activce X controls.

when i try to insert Activce X controls (just normal basic button)
excel give me "Cannot insert object" message box.

And It's same with my colleague's computer.
Is only us having this problem today?
and was there had any MS-updates related to this issue yesterday?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/94d0b004-3303-421d-9ed2-351683b89d08/sudden-problems-with-inserting-activex-basic-controls-such-as-command-buttons?forum=officeitproprevious

found out the solution.

Quit Excel.
Start Windows Explorer.
Select the system drive (usually C:).
Use the Search box to search for *.exd
Delete all found files.

(Thanks to Excel MVP RoryA for this tip)
Regards, Hans Vogelaar (http://www.eileenslounge.com)

Comment: Search inside C:\Users\[user.name]\AppData\Local\Temp for finding files faster.   Actual file locations are "C:\Users\[user.name]\AppData\Local\Temp\Excel8.0\MSForms.exd" and "C:\Users\[user.name]\AppData\Local\Temp\VBE\MSForms.exd"

Answer (score 1):

The same thing happened to me today.  Not only could I not insert the activex object, but the one I had used for a number of years would not work.  Apparently both answers are correct.  Microsoft advised to find and delete the *.exd files or use the fix-it tool under for symptom 1 in their Office Configuration Analyzer Tool 1.2 (which I downloaded).  I used the fix-it tool, which worked.

So the credit must go to Stackoverflow.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to find .exd files in C:\, but used Microsoft Office Configuration Analyzer Tool 1.2 and fixed it.  When you run the tool for Excel, you will see critical, warning and informational.  One of the warning shows or relates the symptom like "Cannot insert object" error in an ActiveX custom Office solution after you install the MS14-082 security update.  I used the "Fix It" button under Resolution for symptom 1.  It worked.

Comment: Do you have any source to back that up?